# Unable to post values from Multiselect drop down in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, multi-select

I am unable to post values from multi select drop down. Actual problem is in the edit profile part of user in this section i am not able to post values of already selected values from database. 
This is my html part

```
<select name="drop_caste[]" id="cast_to" class="form-control new-two"   size="8" multiple="multiple">
<?php foreach($selectedcast->result() as $row): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row->cid; ?>" ><?php echo $row->caste ; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?> </select>
</select>
```

This is the code i am using to post the value

```
$this->input->post('drop_caste');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `drop_caste` into an array as

```
$data['drop_caste'] = $this->input->post('drop_caste');
print_r($data);// here you get your value
```

**OR** you can use `foreach loop` for it

```
foreach($this->input->post("drop_caste") as $drop_caste){
    echo $drop_caste;
}
```

**OR** you can direct change POST array in to string

`$caste = implode(',',$this->input->post("caste"));`

Answer (score 0):

**JS:**

Trigger this on some action:

```
var config = { learn : [] };

$('#learn_multiselect option:selected').map(function(a, item){
   config.learn.push( { "id" : item.value } );
});

   //write code for ajax to send this config object using ajax to your controller
   //something like this

    $.ajax({
        url: $url,
        method: $method,
        data: $dataArr,
        dataType: $dataType,
        contentType: $contentType
    }).done(function(data){
        //handle as required
    }).fail(function(data){
        //handle as required
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id="learn_multiselect" multiple="multiple">
                      <option value="1">Science</option>
                      <option value="2">Maths</option>
</select>
```

Now you should be able to get the POSTED(or what ever method you used in AJAX) data in your controller.